# Relationship of Bias and size of dataset

Tags: data-mining, cross-validation, variance

I was reading the following book: http://www.feat.engineering/resampling.html where the author mentioned the below:

> Generally speaking, as the amount of data in the analysis set shrinks,
> the resampling estimate’s bias increases. In other words, the bias in
> 10-fold cross-validation is smaller than the bias in 5-fold
> cross-validation.

I am unable to understand what the author is trying to say here. My understanding is, as we reduce the size of the dataset, we can induce bias that, a certain sample is restricted to those values only, which is not true since it's just a sample of a larger set. Is this what the author meant? If so, then how does 10-fold cross-validation has a smaller bias than 5-fold cross-validation, since the 10-fold cross-validation will have fewer samples in each fold, than a 5-fold cross-validation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In K fold cross validation, the training data is divided into K folds. In each iteration of training fold K-1 subset are used for training the model and one of the subsets is used for validation.The error estimation is averaged over all k trials to get total effectiveness of our model.

As can be seen, every data point gets to be in a validation set exactly once, and gets to be in a training set k-1 times. This **significantly reduces bias as we are using most of the data for fitting**, and also significantly reduces variance as most of the data is also being used in validation set.